# Http requests while Tomcat is shutting down are blocked - how to change that

Tags: java, spring, rest, tomcat, servlets

I have an application (with Spring) which has REST service (healthcheck) and it is called once per 10 sec. If I run catalina.sh stop the application and tomcat are stopping - any new http healthcheck requests are blocked. 
I would like to pause closing app / tomcat (after catalina.sh) until I get one more healthcheck status - tomcat shouldn't reject new http requests.
It's not SpringBoot (embeded tomcat)
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: What's the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: If I run catalina.sh stop, my application shoud wait for one more healthcheck request (via http), then respond with specific HttpStasus code (eg. 410) and after that it should stop working. The problem is that if I run catalina.sh stop, tomcat block any new http requests.

Comment: Maybe you can signale your app that it is shutting down in some other way, sleep 10 seconds and then invoke catalina.sh stop

Comment: Yes. This is perfect solution. Thanks